# SUMO osm map signals not showing

Tags: network-traffic, traffic-simulation

Aoa,
i have downloaded .osm file from openstreetmap website and installed python 3.5.1. and sumo-win32-0.25.0 and applied following commands:

netconvert --osm-files map.osm -o map.net.xml

polyconvert --net-file map.net.xml --osm-files map.osm --type-file typemap.xml -o map.poly.xml

python C:/Uni.work/FYP/project.work/sumo-0.19.0/tools/trip/randomTrips.py -n map.net.xml -e 100 -l

python C:/Uni.work/FYP/project.work/sumo-0.19.0/tools/trip/randomTrips.py -n map.net.xml -r map.rou.xml -e 100 -l

Copy and edit config file (test.sumo.cfg) ------> map.sumo

additional files ------> map.poly.xml

sumo-gui map.sumo.cfg

Note: my osm file name is map.osm

The sumo runs correctly and gives output of map.osm file, also it shows the running vehicles, **but traffic signals are not shown in the sumo simulator.**

Please help me applying signals in the simulator.

Comment: Your commands look OK. Could you check whether the network contains traffic lights by opening map.net.xml in a text editor and searching for `type="traffic_light"`?

Comment: map.net.xml file doesnot contain type="traffic_light".

Comment: Then it is not a problem with the GUI but with netconvert. Can you post the coordinates of the map (bounding box) you are trying to extract? Maybe the traffic signals there are flagged in a way sumo does not recognize.

Comment: Yeah, there was problem with coordinates, now everything's ok.

Comment: Can you help me with this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267540/how-to-import-data-from-openstreet-map-to-eworld-then-to-sumo]